# Не обновляется приложение в Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Залил приложение в Google Play — оно не обновляется. Версия 8 — при скачивании указывается версия 7.

Почему так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно порядка 2 часов на обновление баз гугла

Comment: Дак прошло уже более 7 часов

Comment: Вообще то нужно около суток - проверено